# Alarm intent doesnt work if somebody call

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

Everything is allright if nobody calls. If i use Opera, or Gmail, or other app it`s ok. And in time target alarm intent start.

```
Intent i2 = new Intent();
i2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i2, 0);

curtimeset = System.currentTimeMillis();
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, curtimeset + full, pIntent); //full time in mills when alarm will be on even from lock mode
```

when Timer start and curr time is equal target time. App start intent. To load it from foreground.

```
public void instanceinitiale() {
    Intent resumeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
    resumeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(resumeIntent);

}
```

How to load my alarm in spite of any situations?)

Answer (score 0):

when it is time to alarm, system will call your application. Same intent(that you use while creating alarm) will be sent you by system. if you put your data while creating it, you can get it

```
public class AlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final static String action="android.intent.action.ALARMHANDLERACTIVITY";
public AlarmService(){
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent.getAction().compareTo(action)==0){
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}




public void createAlarm(){
    Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARMHANDLERACTIVITY");
    intent.putExtra("eventID", Integer.valueOf(id));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,0);
    AlarmManager aManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, temp.getStartDate().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

}
```

to define your receiver wirte this to application block of manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".alarmService.AlarmService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="200">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: if it worked, please consider to accept the answer to help others